# My kernel is stuck processing simple code (web-scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to do some pretty simple web-scraping with beautifulsoup, and I am using the requests.get command, to fetch HTML data from a website.
However, from this given website, my kernel can't seem to process the request, and my kernel gets stuck.
Has anyone experienced this before and found a solution?

I'm simply trying the following:

> r = requests.get('http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/etp/leverage-certifikat/info?Instrument=CSE192562')

Comment: what do you mean by kernel gets stuck ? , can you post the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, this website requires some headers to load , which you can pass in the request

as

```
>>>requests.get('http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/etp/leverage-certifikat/info?Instrument=CSE192562', headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"})
<Response [200]>
```